# Javascript (React) Two OAuth Methods, How can I close the window of one when I have logged in with the other?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, office365, google-oauth

So our company offers Google and Office 365 OAuth, and I would like to be able to do one of several things under certain, very specific, circumstances.

1. If the customer is not logged in, they have the option of both login buttons. If the customer then clicks both and proceeds to login with one, I   want to be able to close any other popups.
2. If the customer has a cookie open for google auth, we automatically log them in, but since there is a delay, they can easily click the office login button. I want to be able to close that popup on redirect.
3. If the customer closes/navigates away, I want to be able to close those popups if either or both are open.

Its hard to search for answers to this, as accessing the Google OAuth window is not easy, and trying to detect and then act upon a child window from a parent is equally difficult.

Thanks for any help or resources